# Pulumi does not perform graceful shutdown of kubernetes pods

Tags: docker, kubernetes, pulumi

I'm using pulumi to manage kubernetes deployments. One of the deployments runs an image which intercepts SIGINT and SIGTERM signals to perform a graceful shutdown like so (this example is running in my IDE):

```
{"level":"info","msg":"trying to activate gcloud service account","time":"2021-06-17T12:19:25-05:00"}
{"level":"info","msg":"env var not found","time":"2021-06-17T12:19:25-05:00"}
{"Namespace":"default","TaskQueue":"main-task-queue","WorkerID":"37574@Paymahns-Air@","level":"error","msg":"Started Worker","time":"2021-06-17T12:19:25-05:00"}
{"Namespace":"default","Signal":"interrupt","TaskQueue":"main-task-queue","WorkerID":"37574@Paymahns-Air@","level":"error","msg":"Worker has been stopped.","time":"2021-06-17T12:19:27-05:00"}
{"Namespace":"default","TaskQueue":"main-task-queue","WorkerID":"37574@Paymahns-Air@","level":"error","msg":"Stopped Worker","time":"2021-06-17T12:19:27-05:00"}
```

Notice the `"Signal":"interrupt"` with a message of `Worker has been stopped`.

I find that when I alter the source code (which alters the docker image) and run `pulumi up` the pod doesn't gracefully terminate based on what's described in [this blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace). Here's a screenshot of logs from GCP:

[image]

The highlighted log line in the image above is the first log line emitted by the app. Note that the shutdown messages aren't logged above the highlighted line which suggests to me that the pod isn't given a chance to perform a graceful shutdown.

Why might the pod not go through the graceful shutdown mechanisms that kubernetes offers? Could this be a bug with how `pulumi` performs updates to deployments?

---

EDIT: after doing more investigation I found that this problem is happening because starting a docker container with `go run /path/to/main.go` actually ends up created two processes like so (after `exec`ing into the container):

```
root@worker-ffzpxpdm-78b9797dcd-xsfwr:/gadic# ps aux
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root           1  0.3  0.3 2046200 30828 ?       Ssl  18:04   0:12 go run src/cmd/worker/main.go --temporal-host temporal-server.temporal.svc.cluster.local --temporal-port 7233 --grpc-port 6789 --grpc-hos
root        3782  0.0  0.5 1640772 43232 ?       Sl   18:06   0:00 /tmp/go-build2661472711/b001/exe/main --temporal-host temporal-server.temporal.svc.cluster.local --temporal-port 7233 --grpc-port 6789 --
root        3808  0.1  0.0   4244  3468 pts/0    Ss   19:07   0:00 /bin/bash
root        3817  0.0  0.0   5900  2792 pts/0    R+   19:07   0:00 ps aux
```

If run `kill -TERM 1` then the signal isn't forwarded to the underlying binary, `/tmp/go-build2661472711/b001/exe/main`, which means the graceful shutdown of the application isn't executed. However, if I run `kill -TERM 3782` then the graceful shutdown logic *is* executed.

It seems the `go run` spawns a subprocess and [this blog post](https://medium.com/@gchudnov/trapping-signals-in-docker-containers-7a57fdda7d86#.7noi7qvsy) suggests the signals are only forwarded to PID 1. On top of that, it's unfortunate that `go run` doesn't forward signals to the subprocess it spawns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to add `RUN go build -o worker /path/to/main.go` in my dockerfile and then to start the docker container with `./worker --arg1 --arg2` instead of `go run /path/to/main.go --arg1 --arg2`.

Doing it this way ensures there aren't any subprocess spawns by `go` and that ensures signals are handled properly within the docker container.